# VBA script - Compile error: wrong number of arguments

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement, cell

I'm trying to create a basic VBA script to check a column of cells and add something to the same row of a different column if a specific value is found.

I spent hours on this and originally it ran but gave no result. Now I re-factored the code and no matter what I do, I get a Compile error:

> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.

This is my code -

```
    Sub Price_Check()

    Dim i As Integer, SearchList As Range, Price As Currency
    SearchList = Range("R1:R5000")
    Price = 3.99
    i = 0
    For Each cell In SearchList
    i = i + 1
        If cell.Value = Price Then
            Cells.Value(2, i) = 2000
    End If
    Next cell

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Price_Check()

Dim i As Integer, SearchList As Range, Price As Currency
Dim sht As Worksheet, cell As Range

Set sht = ActiveSheet 'always best to specify a sheet, 
                      '  even if it's the default one

Set SearchList = sht.Range("R1:R5000") '<< added "Set"
Price = 3.99
i = 0
For Each cell In SearchList
    i = i + 1
    If cell.Value = Price Then
        sht.Cells(2, i).Value= 2000 '<< not Cells.Value(2, i)
                                    '  is i supposed to be the row though?
                                    '  Here it is the column
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much. And yes you were also correct that I had the row/column mixed up. After changing that it worked perfectly. I can't than you enough.